# TypeScript Sinon callsFake return type mismatch

Tags: typescript, sinon

I keep getting this error when I try to call a fake function using a sinon stub. 
`[ts] Argument of type '(contactStructure: ContactStructure, sourceValue: any) => Promise<{ value: undefined; failure: { contactStructure: ContactStructure; sourceValue: any; }; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => any'. [2345]`
I'm on version 7.1.1 of sinon and version 5.0.6 of @types/sinon

this is my stub:

```
private cnctMappingMngrStub:SinonStubbedInstance<ContactMappingManager>;
before(): void {
  this.cnctMappingMngrStub = createStubInstance(ContactMappingManager);
}
```

This is where I'm calling the fake.

```
  this.cnctMappingMngrStub.getMappedValue
  .onCall(1).callsFake(async (contactStructure: ContactStructure, sourceValue: any) => {
    return Promise.resolve({
      value: undefined,
      failure: {
        contactStructure,
        sourceValue
      }
    });
  });
```

I think I understand what the issue is... I think. It's giving this error because the return type of to function is `() => any` when it wants it to be `Promise<{ value: undefined; failure: { contactStructure: ContactStructure; sourceValue: any; }; }>`. I just don't know how to fix it. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

~ Ethan

Comment: may you share your source code for `getMappedValue`?

Comment: @deerawan sadly I cannot share that code. I'm sorry.